# Function body is not active

Tags: function, anylogic

I have a problem writing function body in anylogic. I think the answer is pretty easy but i cant find it! when im going to write function body in one of my objects it turns to green color and seems not working for shortcuts like Ctrl+Space. Do you know how to solve this problem?
[image: Function body problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have another function in which you commented some code block using

```
/*
```

What you need to do is find where you did that and close the block comment using

```
*/
```

So this would be wrong:

```
    /*
int mycode=0;
someFunction();
```

This would be correct:

```
/*
    int mycode=0;
    someFunction();
    */
```